# How to configure java call to batch, auto confirming " Do you want to let this prog making modification to this computer ...."?

Tags: java, batch-file

The command needs a response from user to confim execution of devcon, i would like to shortcut this to be automatic .

How can i do that ?

Thank you

My code is :

from java call :

```
String[] command = {"cmd.exe","/C","Start","C:\\Applications\\Jamie\\lib\\DesActiveComBluetooth"};
                Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process p = r.exec(command);
```

batch file:

```
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% EQU AMD64  GOTO 64BIT
REM (ici donc on traite du 32 bits)
devcon32 disable bthenum\{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}
GOTO END

:64BIT
REM (ici donc on traite du 64 bits)
devcon64 disable bthenum\{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}
GOTO END

:END
REM (fin du programme)

PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 2000 >NUL
exit
```

Comment: If you could circumvent that, that wouldn't be a good security measure, would it?

Comment: i can't see why. devcon is a well known exe, it is just a way to avoid the user to say yes each time he use the programm.

Comment: Ok, but imagine you were running anything else. I'd still expect the operating system to require manual intervention from the user. Otherwise any malicious program could just do what you're trying to do, circumvent that popup and have access to the machine without user intervention, which would defeat the purpose of windows' UAC (that is, the prompt you're getting). See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/99286/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-7), I'm not sure it still works for Windows 10, but it's a start.

Comment: I agree whith your comments , btw this is code i freshly retrieve and have to adapt.